# What to do with questions that have terrible answers that don't answer the question posed?

Tags: discussion, questions, specific-question, answer-quality, popularity

I came across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5255571/passing-price-variable-to-paypal-with-custom-button) and out of all the answers I don't think I found *one* answer that actually provided a solution to the question posed by the user.

There were possible solutions posted by people, which most involved creating the Paypal button in a different (and unsecure) method; whilst these answers may provide a method for what the user wanted to do - they fail to do so in the manner the user was asking about.

I don't think I have seen a SO question with such poor answers before, several with many upvotes.

Comment: Well, what would you *want* to do? You can downvote the existing answers, leave a comment explaining why they are a bad idea or don't work, and post a better answer of your own. Pick any one, or all three.

Comment: Well they are misleading and unhelpful to future viewers. Downvoting a answer which already has 14 upvotes isn't going to be much use is it!? The answers should be deleted as they do not address the issue.

Comment: *I don't think I found one answer that actually provided a solution to the question posed by the user* That is strange because there is an accepted answer.

Comment: That is not a precedent we want to set, Brett. You, me, nor any of the moderators should go around making executive decisions about which answers to delete when there is a strong community consensus to the opposite. As you said, there are 14 upvotes—at least 14 people found those answers useful. If you think they are poor answers, then you should downvote them. You're right, it won't make much of a difference, so this would probably be a good time to leave a comment explaining *why* the answers are problematic. Smart people will read it. Those who don't aren't looking for your help.

Comment: What to expect from the _PHP community_ anyways?

Comment: with 32K views question seems to be rather popular, this is known to attract garbage answers

Comment: @rene Just because it was accepted doesn't mean it answered the question that was asked.

Comment: @CodyGray Fair enough. I can understand that.

Comment: The OP judged differently ...

Comment: @CodyGray FWIW precedent for something like that was set by Atwood in his answer here: [How aggressively should we maintain and improve very popular questions?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/103069/165773) Though granted this particular question has 5x-10x less votes that could justify spending effort of a diamond moderator on an "aggressive maintenance"